# About an answer given for Project Euler 19

Tags: probability, project-euler, calendar-computations

The problem is [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=19) and someone gave this answer but I don't understand it even if I know the rule of large numbers.

> If you want to write a code for this, it is really boring. On the other hand, if someone asks you if some day is Sunday, the probability of yes is 1/7. The rule of large numbers  indicate that over many guesses (n), the number of your true guess will approach n/7 as n gets large. So for 120 months in 20th century, it's enough to check integers close to 1200/7=171.4.., which are 171 and 172 and by far less probability 170 and 173. The answer is 171 :)

I don't understand when he says "the number of your true guess will approach n/7" and also why he divided "1200" and not "120" by 7 ?

**EDIT:** I would like to understand why he used the probability of a sunday in a week and not a sunday in a month ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The occurrence of "120" instead of "1200" is a typo.

Comment: What "typo" means ? sorry i'm french ^^

Comment: Sorry, it's short for "typographical error" ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error)), i.e., the person meant to write "1200" but made a mistake in writing.

Comment: Oh yeah, i'm the Jean Claude Van Dam of maths, on my head 12*100=120 lol. Sorry. x)

Comment: Well now i would like to understand why he used the probability of one sunday in a week and not in a month... :/

Comment: The number of Sundays in a month varies from month to month (some have more, others have fewer), but there are always the same number of Sundays in a week.

Comment: It makes sence now thank you ! :)